# Changing the "My Code Reviews & Requests" in TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-code-review

Somehow I have changed the TFS 2012 query that is used for code reviews. This query can be found under "My Work" in VS 2012 towards the bottom. I can see the guts of the query by selecting "open query" next to the title "My Code Reviews & Requests" and then selecting "edit query". However, it is not possible to save this query in a way that will change the "My Code Reviews & Requests" or at least I can't see it.

The issue that I have is that someone the query has been changed from the default and I don't know how to get it back to the default. This issue is isolated to me and this specific TFS instance. I can connect to a different TFS instance and see the default query using the same steps as above so I am relatively certain that this issue is related to a specific TFS instance and not my local machine.

Comment: Try using File->Save All.

Comment: After selecting "edit query" I get a new query window and of course I can save the query in the normal ways but I am forced to put the query into "my queries" or "shared queries". My questions is not related to a new query but how to change the exact query behind "My Code Reviews & Requests" or how to revert this query back to the out of the box state.

Comment: I haven't used TFS 2012 yet, but are you sure the query isn't already in "Shared Queries" or something like that?

Comment: I am sure the queries are not in the "Shared Queries" folder. This issue is isolated to me and to a specific TFS service. I have confirmed this by logging into different TFS instances from my machine and working with coworkers to log into the same TFS instances. Only me logging into a specific TFS instance is affected (or infected depending on your point of view).

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to change this query. It appears to be hard coded and my attempts to edit it result in saving a new query like you say.

Comment: I am having a similar problem except in my case I need to change the default query to something else because one of the fields referenced by it is a field I had to redefine because we already had a field by the same Name. So I need to change the column referencing Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy to instead reference SoftBrands.ReviewedBy. It looks like I can use the dropdown to select a different query instead, but I'd like to "correct" the default query. Will return if I find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try voting on this Microsoft bug to see if it pushes for an improvement in TFS design by allowing more control over the queries generated by the My Work view:

[Queries listed under My Work cannot be corrected](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799330/queries-listed-under-my-work-cannot-be-corrected)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you change that so as I guess you customize the process if so? Of course this happen to existing project but as I guess it will not happen for new project??? if so you can download the existing project that has the issue and create new project using the same process template and try to compare the 2 process to know what is the different and how you can change that.